# Admin 404 Error after saved

Tags: 404-page, 404, magento2.3.0

Using Magrento 2.3
Admin back-end 404 Error after saved.

> 404 Error Page not found.

Need to refresh can save everytime, how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Can you be more informative?
url, page, action ?

Comment: In backend everywhere when i after saved will be 404 and then need to refresh, it will saved , how to fix it thank you! @MilindSingh

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion 1:

Make sure you have right permission for folder generated and pub(basically this folder will be in correct permission and you would have got 500 Internal server on installing or accessing the site after installation).

make sure generated folder is having 777 permission.

Suggestion 2:

try to clear you web static content and add it again.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

if it said already exists or like that,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

force it with

> -f

command like above.

Already some of the similar questions are available from other users.

Comment: Yes, we ran chmod -R -v 777 generated and -f but not working. 404 still when after save.

Comment: Did u modify your .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes @SridharG.K

Comment: That might cause admin url to break. Please check reverting it back to it's original state

Comment: Please check original post and i tried back original state still is same. @SridharG.K

Comment: Before we ran command is this `sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;` 
`sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;` 
`sudo chown -R user:user .` 
`sudo chmod u+x bin/magento` @SridharG.K

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same problem and its driving me crazy